# Difference in usage of "all right", "ok", "very well"

Tags: word-choice, differences, british-english

When I agree with doing something annoying or what I originally didn't want to do is there a difference between starting the reply with: "all right", "ok", "very well" or others?

Does "very well" sound posh or archaic? I hear it all the time when watching old episodes of Doctor Who (60's) but I don't recall hearing it in the wild in England.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of the three, "Very well" has the strongest connotation of giving in to a decision you disagree with. But I also never hear it spoken "in the wild," as you say; I would say that it is certainly formal, and I wouldn't expect to hear a young person say it. In that way, it seems archaic. It's much like "As you wish."

"OK" we use so often that it might not carry the meaning you intend. "All right" might convey that disagreement better, but I would also suggest using "Fine."

Of course, everything depends on context. If you've already expressed your disagreement with someone and later reply with a curt "All right" as your acquiescence, that person will undoubtedly get the message.

Comment: In spoken English, the tone of voice used will carry more meaning than the specific choice of phrase.