# Pragmatics and subtle differences in meaning 'good' vs 'all-right', 'ok' etc

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, pragmatics

I've heard and noticed that the word 'good', when used in conversation, has connotations that may not be obvious to an L2 user.

'Good' can be taken to mean, that the person using it is hierarchically superior to the one this is said to. That is, while 'good' is approval, it somehow also says that the person saying it is the boss of the situation. Vs 'all right', 'ok', 'sure' etc. In some other languages, 'good' simply means that it's 'all right' or 'cool', and differences in nuance can be difficult to get in second language.

Example

> A: I finished the task I told you about.
>
> B: Good (Thanks for doing your job. Now that your task is done, we can move on. I'll tell you what to do next.)
>
> A: (Why on earth would you be bossy about it - we're equals!)

Vs

> A: I finished the task I told you about.
>
> B: Great/Nice!/Cool
>
> A: (Cool thing, let's keep working on this.)

Is this so, and are there any authoritative references to point to on this? Is there some general reference on these hidden meanings of common conversational words?

I found one source in this same forum, but 'good' was not addressed: [Difference in usage of "all right", "ok", "very well"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280547/difference-in-usage-of-all-right-ok-very-well)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. To clarify, are you looking to add "good" to the words that you linked to in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280547/difference-in-usage-of-all-right-ok-very-well ? And to clarify further, are you addressing conversational speech for British English or American English?

Comment: I don't think I agree with your assertion about what 'good' means - perhaps you can provide some examples. On the face of it, 'good' has pretty much the same basic meaning as all of: "ok", "all right", "very well" (when used in the same context.)

Comment: Thanks for advising. I added an example. The intuitions are based on British English, but I don't know if it would be limited to it, or maybe it's also rare in British English. There are at least a few confirmations of this from personal life, but I don't know it written down anywhere.

Comment: This sort of usage is very dependent on age, employment area, education etc. For example, as an elderly British academic, I would never use great to mean good, never ever use cool, and rarely use nice. If I mean good I say good.

Comment: 'Good' is certainly more formal than 'Great' / 'Nice' / 'Cool'. And with the more formal ('higher'!) register, I think it's fair to say, comes an automatic nuance of condescension. This is hardly perceptible, however, in the UK, at least among most of the groups I've interacted with – and the way the words are said makes all the difference. / I usually try to give 'back-handed' compliments, like "I bet that took some doing."

Comment: "'Good' can be taken to mean, that the person using it is hierarchically superior to the one this is said to": **That is absolutely not the case.** "good" as a response can be used by anybody anytime when a second person is responding to what a first person has said or done. And it has zero to do with BrE or AmE English. Both use it in the same exact way(s) in speech as a single word response before saying something else afterwards or not.